# Cross-country landmarks/tourist spots near I-40

Tags: usa, driving, road-trips, landmarks

I'm driving cross-country from New England to San Francisco in a few days. I'll have company all the way up until Memphis. After that, I'm on my own.

I'll be taking I-40 through Arkansas, Oklahoma, Texas, New Mexico, Arizona, and California. I'd like to have a few stops during the daytime (not too long, 1-2 hours tops) to break up the monotony. They can't be too far off of the highway. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Arizona there is the [Meteor Crater](http://www.meteorcrater.com/)

There is the [Continental Divide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aContinental_Divide_and_I-40.jpg)

There are [Grand Canyon Caverns](http://www.gccaverns.com/), but this may be a little out of the way but driving on old US-66 might just break the monotony and then get back on I-40.

There is the [Mojave National Preserve](http://www.nps.gov/moja/index.htm).

Generally though you can probably find more on the [Road Trip America site](http://www.roadtripamerica.com/)

Comment: In addition to Road Trip America, also suggest [Roadside America](http://www.roadsideamerica.com/) which focuses more on quirky / Americana items. Lots o' fun stuff there!

Comment: @BrendanMcK Edit the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend the [Painted Desert](http://www.arizonaguide.com/places-to-visit/arizona-parks-monuments/the-painted-desert) and [Petrified Forest](http://www.nps.gov/pefo/index.htm). They are near Holbrook, Arizona. Very interesting and great for taking pictures. You could get out of the car and stop and stretch your legs at several places along the drive through the parks.

Answer (score 0):

The Grand Canyon is wonderful, but a long way from I-40.  Meteor Crater is close, and very underappreciated.  It really is a cool spot.  You will learn, relax, and have time to hike around a little.  Which are all things that are good when on a long trip.  I'm about to do a similar trip, from Winston Salem to Phoenix, along I-40 most of the way.  In Arizona, Meteor Crater would be my #1 spot on that highway.  :-)